# Bookmark with timeout in WF 4.0 when persisted

Tags: c#, workflow-foundation-4

I have been looking around for a while now and I want to create a timeout property on a bookmark in WF 4.0.

I can make it work with using a Picker with two different branches (and have a timer in one of them and my bookmark in the other).

However this does not work if my workflow is persisted to the database (which it will be since the timeout will be several days) since it will not trigger until i load the workflow next time which can be several days also.

Does anyone know if there is any other way to solve this in the WF 4.0? Or have you done a great workaround?

Comment: What purpose does the bookmark serve?  Are you wanting to restart it by "calling" the bookmark?

Comment: The purpose is that we send out an item to be reviewed by a user of our system and if the user does not respond in say like seven days we want to start different workflows depending on the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so what you're going to want to do is build a Workflow Service, you will not be able to do this via a workflow that is **not** hosted via the Workflow Service Host (WSH) near as easily.  To tell you it can't be done would be incorrect, but I can tell you that you don't **want** to.

That service will be available via a WCF endpoint and can do **exactly** what you're needing.  You would be able to build a workflow that had a pick branch that had two things in it, the first is a Receive activity that could be called into by the user if they responded in time.  The second would be a durable timer that ticked at a specified interval and would allow you to branch down another path.  Now this same service can have more than one Receive activity and thus exposing more than one endpoint so if your workflow has any other branches just like this you can handle all of those in one atomic workflow.

Does this make sense?